# На всех страницах показываются картинки, на другом не показывают

Tags: php

На всех страницах показывают картинки

[image]

Если на другом странице(на одном, где там какая-то ошибка), то не показывают картинки и еще тоже шрифт

[image]

Comment: эта ошибка называется "неправильно указан путь до картинки"

Comment: Но у меня правильный, такое меню на всех страницах

Comment: Если бы было правильный, то картинка отображалась бы

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.